# How to restrict acces to login form if user is authenticated?

Tags: symfony

I used the basic login form in symfony2 and it works well ( without FOSUSERBUNDLE ).
But how to restrict acces if a user is already authenticated ?

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) { }
```

the code above does not work because the login route is not under the firewall... and throw :

> The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

How to solve it ?

Comment: put the login route under firewall.

Comment: really ? reading the doc I thought contrary that it should not ... I am confused

Comment: I don't understand how can users acces to the login form if it's under firewall...

Answer (score 2):

As said, the login url must be under firewall if you want to have access to the token/authenticated user. This is possible allowing anonymous access and proper access control rules.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        # firewall settings
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use firewall
Example of firewall:

```
firewalls:
         main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /
                login_path: /
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /main
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target : /
            anonymous: true
            security: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/main, roles: ["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"] }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ["ROLE_ADMIN"] }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html

Comment: I already use firewall, do you mean that bypass of login form if user is already authenticated should be automaticaly handle by symfony ?